# How to provide JavaScript library for mobile native apps?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, nativescript, hybrid-mobile-app

I am not a mobile developer, hence please excuse me for incorrect assumptions, if any

I have a library which users want to integrate in their native mobile apps. It is written in JavaScript, but I don't want to rewrite for Android and iOS. Hence what I need is some way that this JavaScript library can be used in native apps. Following two ways look promising:

- WebViews: The JS files would reside locally and webview will be used to run them
- NativeScript: NativeScript allows you to create native apps from JavaScript. But I didn't find anything which suggests that I can create native library too. Can this be used in any way?

Comment: Unless the JavaScript library taps into browser API, or expects some node.js functionality or modules, then you can use the library in NativeScript any concerns.

Comment: @pkanev Thanks. One more clarification. I won't be creating users app, they already have it. I just need to provide a library. So, can I create this library using NativeScript?

Comment: NativeScript normally outputs applications. In its core are embedded the JavaScript Core and v8 JavaScript VMs for iOS and Android respectively. It's those two components that provide the functionality of executing JavaScript. Perhaps you may want to embed NativeScript into an existing native application to take advantage of that part of NativeScript? https://docs.nativescript.org/integration-with-existing-ios-and-android-apps/extend-existing-android-app

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)
It is a Javascript framework, and when you write your code, most of the time, you can use the same code for iOS and Android. It is a relatively new framework, but can be very powerful for rapid cross-development, but (obviously) has its trade-offs.

Comment: But can I write libraries which can be used by native developers?

Comment: Of course! There are a ton of libraries and packages constantly being written for react native. [Check out all of the libraries that have already been written that are at your disposal](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=react+native)